# Get Value from Array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am passing data into array from mysql query and getting it into javascript
which is display like this

> Data:{"0":[{"Question":"abc","Answer":"abc 123"},{"Question":"xyz","Answer":"xyz 123 "}],
>   "message":"Success"}

Now I want to get all Question in one variable and related FAQ_Answer in another variable and display like

> Question : abc
>   Answer : abc 123
>
> Question : xyz
>   Answer : xyz 123

But the problem is that I don't know how to get related question and its answer from an array.

I tried all the methods like data[0][0] or etc. but it is giving me undefined or [object,object] type of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it can be done:

```
var data = {Data:{"0":[{"Question":"abc","Answer":"abc 123"},{"Question":"xyz","Answer":"xyz 123 "}], "message":"Success"}};
var qaList = data.Data['0'];

// build HTML in div from questions and answers
var div = document.getElementById('qa');
for (var i = 0; i < qaList.length; ++i) {
    var qa = qaList[i];
    div.innerHTML += 'Question : '+qa.Question+' Answer : '+qa.Answer+'<br/>';
} // end for
```

http://jsfiddle.net/61uv7jnj/

Comment: This is exact what i need
thanks for the jsfiddle demo ... :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to read some documentation about javascript syntax a little :p .

In this case, let's assume you have =:

```
var data = {"0":[{"Question":"abc","Answer":"abc 123"}]};
```

It is read like this: data is an object, containing a single key named "0", which is a reference to an array. The array contains a single entry. That entry is an object containing 2 keys, "Question" and "Answer", each being a string.

So, with that said:

```
data // is the object
data[0] // references the array of questions, note that it is in fact data["0"]
data[0][0] // references the first entry in the array of questions
data[0][0].Question // contains the first question's text
data[0][0].Answer // contains the first question's answer
```

Typically, you'd make a variable that represents what your dealing with to make it clear to whoever reads the code, e.g.

```
var first_question = data[0][0];
```

and use the properties from then on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and detailed answer, i'll follow that steps for future use and for my knowledge. But another answer is exact what i want so i marked it as the right answer.